# accessing and changing user data header in java smslib

Tags: java, header, sms, smslib

I have used java smslib api to send an sms from pc to mobile using a gsm modem. I wanted to know if it is possible to send images and short audio clips through sms using this. I have heard that by changing the user data header of the message, this can be done.

Am I going on the right track? 
if yes, how do I proceed with this since i am new to java programming.

I have gone through many links specifying the user data header. but I haven't come accross how to access this header.

any kind of help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an MMS. smslib.org specifically says that it doesn't support MMS.

An MMS is not the same as an ordinary SMS - it's sent over an HTTP/WAP connection.  So you can't just manipulate an SMS header and get an MMS.

You could look at JSR 205, it supports MMS.

Answer (score 0):

newbee, too small images and audios, that were once sent via sms can be sent; they are encoded as the separate InformationElement of UDH, please see the

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header

Smslib allows to encode the UDH, but I think you should checkout the full source code of the smslib and dive into it to find where the UDHs are formed there. At least the concatenated sms are sent with smslib through the manipulation with UDH IEIs.